# How to return a table and its total count in postgres' function

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I am newer to postgresql and create function as the below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetLogs(
    _from Date, 
    _to Date,  
    _sortBy TEXT, 
    _orderby INT, 
    _page INT, 
    _row INT)
 RETURNS TABLE (
     "Id" UUID, 
     "RequestHeaders" text, 
     "RequestContent" text, 
     "ResponseHeaders" text, 
     "ResponseContent" text, 
     "ResponseCode" integer, 
     "ExecutionTimeMs" integer, 
     "Description" text,
     "RecordedOn" timestamp with time zone, 
     "Username" character varying, 
     "Exception" text) 
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM dbo."Logs" log
        where log."RecordedOn" >= $1 and log."RecordedOn" <= $2;

    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT log.*
        FROM dbo."Logs" log
        where log."RecordedOn" >= $1 and log."RecordedOn" <= $2
        Offset ($5-1) * $6
        Limit $6;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

, and call it using

```
select * from GetLogs('2020-02-11','2020-02-12','Date',0,1,10)
```

I expect it will be a count and table data, but error is

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type bigint does not match expected type uuid in column 1.
```

can anybody solve it ?

Comment: The first `RETURN QUERY` still needs to return the structure you defined that function to return. Instead you return a single `BIGINT`. What format exactly are you expecting to get out of this function? Show an example with the output that you expect to get from a call to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not return result with structure not matched to RETURNS TYPE (in your case 
 - TABLE). 
 Instead this you can use window function for add `RowsCount` to each returned row.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetLogs(
    _from Date, 
    _to Date,  
    _sortBy TEXT, 
    _orderby INT, 
    _page INT, 
    _row INT)
 RETURNS TABLE (
     "Id" UUID, 
     "RequestHeaders" text, 
     "RequestContent" text, 
     "ResponseHeaders" text, 
     "ResponseContent" text, 
     "ResponseCode" integer, 
     "ExecutionTimeMs" integer, 
     "Description" text,
     "RecordedOn" timestamp with time zone, 
     "Username" character varying, 
     "Exception" text,
     "RowsCount" integer
)
AS $$
DECALARE
    RowsCount integer;
BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT log.*, COUNT(*) OVER() AS RowsCount
        FROM dbo."Logs" log
        WHERE log."RecordedOn" >= $1 AND log."RecordedOn" <= $2
        OFFSET ($5-1) * $6
        LIMIT $6;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Can it return multiple result ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it possible to return 2 results with different types